# QT QScreen cannot get any display serial number

Tags: macos, qt

Any of you guys know if QT QScreen could get serial number from either EDID serial number or
EDID string descriptor via 0xff? it always return blank string, in the Display, I set both EDID byte 12-15 and string descriptor.

```
void ScreenHandler::DisplayAdded( QScreen* display )
{
    /*
    std::string displayName = display->name().toStdString();
    std::string model = display->model().toStdString();
    std::string manufacturer= display->manufacturer().toStdString();
    std::string serialNumber = display->serialNumber().toStdString();

    QString displayNameQ = QString::fromStdString(displayName);
```

BTW, Is it possible to get CGDirectDisplayID from QScreen? I saw QScreen
constructor is using it, but never spit back.

Comment: For this one would have to look into the QScreen implementation in the cocoa qpa plugin - probably these functions are just not implemented there...

Comment: Indeed, QCocoaScreen (in qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa) doesn’t reimplement serialNumber() and friends. So this would need to be fixed in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a no go way, I went back to Quartz APIs to detour this problem